# Doctrine2 + CodeIgniter and database table creation issue

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm, entities

I'm using Doctrine2 with codeIgniter, I've created some models in `yml` format. Using command line I've created the Proxies and Entities. When I'm trying to create the database tables, I'm getting the following error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>   Invalid mapping file 'Entities.category.dcm.yml' for class
>   'Entities\category'.

Here's `Entities.category.dcm.yml`:

```
Entities\Category:
  type: entity
  table: categories
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
      nullable: false
    description:
      type: string
      length: 255
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the paths configured for your entities and for the YML mapping driver.

Also, your `Entities.category.dcm.yml` contains mappings for `Entities\Category`, and not `Entities\category`.

As you can see in the base [`FileDriver`](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/2.3.0/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/FileDriver.php#L113-L115) Doctrine ORM does direct matching for mapped classes, and applies no normalization on the class names. `Category` and `category` are therefore different.

Comment: The file name has a capital C `Entities.Category.dcm.yml`

Comment: Your entity has lowercase `c` though.

Comment: from where it is getting the lowercase c? It is capital in both: Filename and at first line inside the file

Comment: @user915829 not in your class name. I can see that from the exception message :)

Comment: I've checked and I have no lowercase c anywhere... other ideas?

Comment: @user915829 can you update the question with the exact error message?

Comment: The error message I provide is the only one I got....I will try with a windows machine...sometimes MAC OS give some problem with doctrine

Comment: @user915829 the error message clearly states `Entities\category` with lowercase `c`. The file defines mappings for `Entities\Category` with uppercase `C`.

Comment: but my question is...since I AM the creator of the entity...and I've created it with the uppercase C, WHY is is looking for a lowercase c?

Comment: Change all the cases so that they match :)